# Make Overpass output incomplete ways

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

This is how I get my data using Overpass API:

```
[out:xml];
way(40,10,35,5)["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|trunk|trunk_link|primary|primary_link|secondary|secondary_link|tertiary|tertiary_link|residential|service|road|track|unclassified|undefined|unknown|living_street"];
(._;>;);
out;
```

Unfortunately I also get nodes that are outside the bounding box, because overpass completes ways. Can I turn that behaviour off so that my result set just contains nodes that are inside the bounding box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following query for this purpose:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way["highway"~"^(motorway|motorway_link|trunk|trunk_link|primary|primary_link|secondary|secondary_link|tertiary|tertiary_link|residential|service|road|track|unclassified|undefined|unknown|living_street)$"];
out geom({{bbox}});
```

Note that the output format of out geom will be slightly different. It's not an issue for overpass turbo. However, you didn't provide any details about your parser.

Comment: It is much better, but when using your query and replacing {{bbox}} e.g. with "53.3951118,9.7304736,53.7394377,10.3251953" I still get a node not inside the bounding box (https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/20951253). And in my result set it appears as "<nd ref="20951253"/>".

Comment: Yes, that's intended and how `out geom`is defined. You'll just receive the node id, but not its lat/lon details. Those "gaps" are necessary to identify missing pieces of your way in the response, otherwise it will be tricky to properly reconstruct the way geometry inside your bbox.

Comment: It makes sense. Still getting shorter or split ways would make sense, too. But, yeah, there are always good reasons why things are different.